# Dynamic Powerpoint field editing from ASP.Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, vba, powerpoint

This is more of a general question, I'm going to be tackling something I've never attempted yet, and it's likely going to use VBA, which I have had no exposure to.

But I have an ASP.NET web forms application that submits information into a database, and what I would like to do upon completion of one of my forms is populate a pre-made Powerpoint document with some of that information and have it emailed as part of an attachment.

The email portion I'll have no problem with, but the opening, editing and saving dynamically will be new.

Is this doable via an ASP.NET app, and is VBA the way to go?  Any tutorials or resources to lead me in the right direction would be incredibly appreciated.  I haven't found much that is helpful yet.

The more that can be done within C#/ASP.NET and as little in javascript, the better but beggars can't be choosers.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=asp.net+powerpoint - plenty of options here: which one suits your needs is better judged by you.  One thing you should avoid if possible is using ASP to automate PPT on the server: it's not designed for this, and MS recommends against it.  I don't see any scenario where VBA or javascript would be involved.

Comment: Thanks for coming out.